# I want to make a Clicker Game in Xamarin(for android), but I don't know that how can I increase always my count every secoud

Tags: service, xamarin

Should I make a service that returns in every secound the *count* to the MainActivity? And if yes, how can I make that?

```
    StartService(new Intent(typeof, MySerivice));
```

What should I supplemend this? And how can I return *count* from the service back to the MainActivity?

Comment: Sry for bad English, and *second

Comment: Do you just want a timer to tick every second that your game is running? Will a simple `Timer` meet your needs? https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Threading.Timer/